# Swift FontAwesome 5 Pro icons don't show programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, font-awesome

In my swift app, I am using the pro version fontawesome. I got the name

```
Font Awesome 5 Pro
    == FontAwesome5Pro-Light
```

and define it in a button as

```
var button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 20, height: 20))
button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "FontAwesome5Pro-Light", size: 20)
button.setAttributedTitle(NSMutableAttributedString(string: "\u{f13d}"), for: .normal)
button.setTitleColor(.systemBlue, for: .normal)
```

"\u{f13d}" is the unicode anchor icon [Cheatsheet for FontAwesome](https://fontawesome.com/v5/cheatsheet/pro/light)

But the icon just comes out with the question mark in the square. If I create a button in the storyboard, set the font, create an outlet and then set the unicode from code behind it displays correctly.

I'm confused as to the cause. Any ideas?

Thanks ^.^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the attributed title cancels the `titleLabel?.font`. Set the font *of the attributed string*.

Comment: I see so I will need to set attributes with the font and then set it to the button.

Comment: @MicahMontoya try setting  the font after setting the title

Comment: Thanks everyone. Setting the font afterward solve it.